# Where can I find the Performance Metrics generated by SageMaker Debugger/Profiler?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, performancecounter, amazon-sagemaker-debugger

Where can I look for the **performance metrics** generated by **Amazon SageMaker Debugger/Profiler**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.`from sagemaker.debugger import ProfilerConfig`

`profiler_config = ProfilerConfig( framework_profile_params=FrameworkProfile(start_step=1, num_steps=2) )`

2.
`from sagemaker.debugger import TensorBoardOutputConfig`

`tensorboard_output_config = TensorBoardOutputConfig(s3_output_path= << add your bucket name an folder >> )`

3. In your estimator - specify :  `profiler_config= profiler_config` and `tensorboard_output_config=tensorboard_output_config`
4. Train your model
5. Go to the s3 bucket specified  for your training job name that is assigned in Sagemaker . You should see a report under **rule-output** > **ProfilerReport** *** > **profiler-output/** > **profiler-report.html**